# TP-Link TL-WR1043ND v3 openwrt firmware

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, firmware, openwrt

I have uploaded a new alternative firmware for TP-Link TL-WR1043ND v3  https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr1043nd.

[image]

Unfortunately, after the upgrade, the connection to the device has been lost.

I log via 192.168.1.1 receives a response ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I can see that DHCP distributes IP, after adding rigidly ip card also does not have to log on.

[image]

How can I try to enter into the machine, or try to restore the old firmware?

Comment: Not familiar with details here but standard firmwares sometimes support telnet (unencrypted) login and alternatives may require ssh (encrypted) connections. Maybe that's it?

Comment: I turned on the PuTTY telnet to try to log on to 192.168.1.1 on port 23, unfortunately, receives a response: Network error: Connection refused

Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Ping gateway router up and running.
After entering the address on the browser, even though the error appears favicon application DD-WRT.

Comment: I chose the wrong port. Correct is 22 and login with root
How to upload a file recovery? I use the command: sysupgrade -v /tmp/[specified firmware].bin

Comment: Ok I worked it out with Tftpd64 restoring the standard software from a TFTP server. You run a program as an administrator, you enter the appropriate address and port, and permanent address of the network card. You hold the WPS button on the router and turn on the power. Standard file is sent, the router runs a shop software tp link.
http://prntscr.com/am81j0
hmm Here they tried but something came out weird.
https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=51074&p=2

Best

Comment: Although the new software malfunctioning hardware has a network of 192.168.1.1, restore to factory default Firmware with its default settings ip 192.168.0.1
After restoring the settings, we can use the standard upload the firmware to the panel of the Web.
I am after regaining control over the device attempted to upload the firmware of an alternative this time from the dd-wrt.
Although the main panel in them appears only v1 hardware. We may be tempted to beta, so I did and everything works the best.

Support> other-downloads> betas>> choose the latest date >> tplink_tl-WR1043ND-v3

Comment: please check out this video 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LL185QYnPg4